# How to pull out every comma, hyphen, underscore, space, and joining remaining words without spaces?

Tags: regex, perl

I guess this would be a rather long regular expression, but is there a way to takeout underscores, spaces, commas, and hyphens from a string and then join the words together in perl?

Example:

```
_Car - Eat, Tree
```

Becomes:

```
CarEatTree
```

Comment: HAVENT U HEARD ITS A [REALLY GRATE LANGUAGE](http://p3rl.org/Inline::PERL) FOR HIT COUNTERS.

Comment: See Inline::PERL (http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Inline::PERL) for more details.

Comment: I think he means "Print Evaluate Read Loop", (i.e. the order of operations for many users)

Comment: http://joelslinux.blogspot.com/2011/05/on-using-perl-print-evaulate-read-loop.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

search for `[_, -]` and replace with the empty string `""`

```
$str = "_Car - Eat, Tree";
$str =~ s/[_, -]//g;
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use a simple substitution:

```
$string =~ s/[_ ,-]//g;
```

Answer (score 4):

This can also be done without regular expressions: [Transliterate: tr///](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tr.html)

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $s = '_Car - Eat, Tree';
$s =~ tr/_ ,\-//d;
print "$s\n";

__END__

CarEatTree
```

Comment: IMO `tr` really is the correct operation for this task. Translate characters directly rather than matching and replacing.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to strip *any* punctuation, you can always use `s/[[:punct:]]//g`

Comment: Naw, that’s two characters longer than `\p{punct}`, and harder to read.  And it’s a *lot* more charcaters than `\pP`, which suffices.

Answer (score 1):

```
my $str = '_Car - Eat, Tree';
$str =~ s/[\_\-\,\s]*//g;
```

Comment: great stuff. Oh I forgot and how would I also pull out a '&' in the string too?

Comment: \What\are\the\backslashes\for\?  Or the `*`, for that matter?

Answer (score 1):

Using the transliteration operator with (d)elete the (c)omplement;

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.012;

my $str = '_Car - Eat, Tree'; 

$str =~ tr/a-zA-Z//cd;

print $str;

__END__
C:\Old_Data\perlp>perl t6.pl
CarEatTree
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the request exactly. Deletes anything that is not a letter.